# throw new Exception not getting caught with Server.GetLastError()

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my controller action I'm catching an exception and adding some additional info before bubbling up to the Application_Error() method

```
ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        var i = 1 / 0;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("My new Exception!", e)
    }
}


private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Breakpoint shows original error! Not my newly thrown one!
    var exception = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick trip to the documentation of the [Exception.GetBaseException Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.getbaseexception(v=vs.110).aspx) clears everything up:

> A chain of exceptions consists of a set of exceptions such that each exception in the chain was thrown as a direct result of the exception referenced in its `InnerException` property. For a given chain, there can be exactly one exception that is the root cause of all other exceptions in the chain. This exception is called the base exception and its `InnerException` property always contains a null reference.

You set the original `Exception` as the `InnerException` of the thrown `Exception`, therefore the original `Exception` **is** the "base exception".

Maybe you shouldn't call `GetBaseException` if you want to see the most recent `Exception` in the chain?

Comment: FUUUU. GetBaseException Was the problem. I forgot I added it and as many times as I went through the object graph in the debugger looked right past it lol. Thanks much for your quick response and help!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call `GetBaseException` because that will give you the original exception. Just do this:

```
var ex = Server.GetLastError();
var inner = ex.InnerException;
```

Here is a quick test to see what `GetBaseException` does:

```
var ex = new Exception("1st");
var ex2 = new Exception("2nd", ex);
var ex3 = new Exception("3rd", ex2);

var exFinal = ex3.GetBaseException();

Console.WriteLine(exFinal.Message);
```

Output: `1st`